# Qual a diferença entre as opções "--soft", "--mixed e "--hard" no git reset?

Tags: git

Gostaria de entender melhor o que cada opção do `git reset` faz:

- `git reset --soft [commithash]`
- `git reset --mixed [commithash]`
- `git reset --hard [commithash]`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Para mostrar melhor o que o [`git reset`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) faz, primeiro vamos estabelecer um "repositório base" e a partir dele usar as diferentes opções do `reset`.

Então a primeira parte será sobre a montagem do "cenário", que ficou um pouco longa e parece que não tem nada a ver com a pergunta, mas tenha paciência que no final (espero) você entenderá, pois na segunda parte eu uso esse "cenário" como base para mostrar o que cada opção do `reset` faz. Vamos lá:

## Montando o "cenário"

Eu montei um pequeno repositório com apenas um arquivo chamado *arq.txt*, com 3 linhas:

```
$ ls
arq.txt

$ cat arq.txt 
primeiro
segundo
terceiro
```

No momento, o repositório está com 3 commits:

```
$ git log --oneline 
668185f (HEAD -> master) terceiro commit
8bc39c6 segundo commit
36da346 primeiro commit

$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

O `git status` mostra que o arquivo não possui modificações, se comparado ao último commit.

Também podemos ver a diferença entre os commits, para sabermos o que mudou de um para outro (isso será importante para entendermos o que as diferentes opções de `reset` fazem).

Primeiro vamos ver a diferença entre o primeiro e segundo commit:

```
$ git diff 36da346 8bc39c6
diff --git a/arq.txt b/arq.txt
index 98fdf1f..e274503 100644
--- a/arq.txt
+++ b/arq.txt
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
 primeiro
+segundo
```

A diferença é que a linha "segundo" foi adicionada ao arquivo (indicado pelo sinal `+` logo antes do texto "segundo"). Já entre o segundo e terceiro commit:

```
$ git diff 8bc39c6 668185f
diff --git a/arq.txt b/arq.txt
index e274503..c14b6c1 100644
--- a/arq.txt
+++ b/arq.txt
@@ -1,2 +1,3 @@
 primeiro
 segundo
+terceiro
```

Foi adicionada a linha "terceiro".

Ou seja, no primeiro commit o arquivo tinha 1 linha, no segundo commit foi adicionada a segunda linha, e no terceiro commit foi adicionada a terceira linha (e é assim que o arquivo está atualmente).

Agora vou adicionar mais uma linha no arquivo e rodar `git add`:

```
$ echo quarto >> arq.txt
$ cat arq.txt 
primeiro
segundo
terceiro
quarto

$ git add arq.txt
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    modified:   arq.txt
```

O arquivo está marcado para ir no próximo commit (*"Changes to be committed"*). Mas em vez de fazer o commit, vou adicionar mais uma linha no arquivo (mas não vou rodar `git add`):

```
$ echo quinto >> arq.txt 
$ cat arq.txt 
primeiro
segundo
terceiro
quarto
quinto

$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    modified:   arq.txt

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   arq.txt
```

Repare que agora o arquivo está tanto em *"Changes to be committed"* (irá no próximo commit) quanto em *"Changes not staged for commit"* (não irá no próximo commit). E entender porque isso acontece é importante para entender o que cada opção do `reset` faz.

#### Por que isso acontece?

Esse cenário que montei serve para entendermos alguns conceitos importantes.

O primeiro é o *working directory* (diretório de trabalho, ou *working tree*, ou *working dir*). É basicamente o que está no seu disco. No caso, é o arquivo que estou mexendo, com as 5 linhas:

```
$ cat arq.txt 
primeiro
segundo
terceiro
quarto
quinto
```

Essas alterações só estarão no próximo commit se eu mandá-las para o *staging area* (que [também é chamada de *index* ou *cache*](https://www.reddit.com/r/git/comments/2szztw/is_the_index_the_same_as_the_staging_area/)). É isso que acontece quando eu faço `git add arquivo`: o conteúdo do arquivo (que está no *working dir*) é mandado para o *staging area*.

Neste caso, somente a quarta linha está no *staging area* (eu fiz um `git add` quando o arquivo tinha 4 linhas), mas a quinta linha não (pois ela foi editada *depois* do `git add`).

Podemos ver as diferenças usando `diff`:

```
$ git diff --cached 
diff --git a/arq.txt b/arq.txt
index c14b6c1..f9efd34 100644
--- a/arq.txt
+++ b/arq.txt
@@ -1,3 +1,4 @@
 primeiro
 segundo
 terceiro
+quarto
```

A opção `--cached` serve para comparar o *cache* (outro nome para *staging area*) com o último commit. E veja que a diferença é a quarta linha.

Já `diff` sem argumentos compara o *working dir* com o *staging area*:

```
$ git diff
diff --git a/arq.txt b/arq.txt
index f9efd34..a166d58 100644
--- a/arq.txt
+++ b/arq.txt
@@ -2,3 +2,4 @@ primeiro
 segundo
 terceiro
 quarto
+quinto
```

E repare que a diferença é a quinta linha.

É por isso que o arquivo está ao mesmo tempo listado para ir e não ir no próximo commit. A quarta linha está no *staging area* e irá no próximo commit. A quinta linha está no *working dir* mas não está no *staging area* e não irá no próximo commit.

Outra maneira de verificar o que está no *staging area* é com o comando `ls-files`:

```
$ git ls-files -s
100644 f9efd34b6e87df23f7b0c0275daaacff6b7ef8f0 0   arq.txt
```

E para ver o conteúdo do arquivo, basta usar `cat-file` passando o hash do arquivo (como tudo no git, não precisa ser o hash todo, apenas um pedaço inicial que não seja ambíguo):

```
$ git cat-file -p f9efd34b6e
primeiro
segundo
terceiro
quarto
```

Como podemos ver, o arquivo que está no *staging area* possui a quarta linha.

---

## Usando reset

Agora que já temos o cenário inicial, vamos ver o que cada opção de reset faz. Lembrando da nossa situação inicial, temos 3 commits:

```
$ git log --oneline 
668185f (HEAD -> master) terceiro commit
8bc39c6 segundo commit
36da346 primeiro commit
```

O HEAD - que de forma simplificada, é o ponteiro para o branch atual ([é um pouco mais que isso, na verdade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/528332/112052)) - está apontando para o `master` (que é o [branch padrão](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Branching-What-a-Branch-Is) - embora [a partir de outubro de 2020](https://www.zdnet.com/article/github-to-replace-master-with-main-starting-next-month/), o nome tenha sido alterado para `main`). Basicamente, o HEAD diz onde estamos, e se criarmos outro commit, ele será colocado depois do commit para o qual o HEAD aponta.

No *staging area* temos a quarta linha do arquivo (que estará no próximo commit), e no *working dir* temos a quarta e quinta linhas.

### `--soft`

A opção `--soft` move o HEAD para o commit indicado, sem mudar o *working dir* e o *staging area*. Ou seja, se eu passar como parâmetro o hash do segundo commit:

```
$ git reset --soft 8bc39c6
```

Agora o HEAD aponta para o commit indicado:

```
$ git log --oneline 
8bc39c6 (HEAD -> master) segundo commit
36da346 primeiro commit
```

Mas o *working dir* continua o mesmo (o arquivo no meu disco continua com as 5 linhas):

```
$ cat arq.txt 
primeiro
segundo
terceiro
quarto
quinto
```

E o *staging area* continua com 4 linhas:

```
$ git diff --cached
diff --git a/arq.txt b/arq.txt
index e274503..f9efd34 100644
--- a/arq.txt
+++ b/arq.txt
@@ -1,2 +1,4 @@
 primeiro
 segundo
+terceiro
+quarto
```

Note que agora o `diff` identificou que a terceira e quarta linhas foram adicionadas. Isso acontece porque agora o último commit é o segundo, e neste commit o arquivo só tinha 2 linhas. Ao compará-lo com o *staging area* (que está com 4 linhas), a diferença está na terceira e quarta linhas.

Vamos conferir também com `ls-files`:

```
$ git ls-files -s
100644 f9efd34b6e87df23f7b0c0275daaacff6b7ef8f0 0   arq.txt
```

Repare que o hash do arquivo continua o mesmo, o que indica que o *staging area* não foi alterado:

```
$ git cat-file -p f9efd34b6e
primeiro
segundo
terceiro
quarto
```

O arquivo que está no *staging area* continua com a quarta linha. Ou seja, `reset --soft` não alterou seu conteúdo.

### `--mixed`

A opção `--mixed` é o *default* se nenhuma das opções for fornecida - mas no exemplo a seguir vou colocá-la só para ficar mais claro que estou usando-a.

Lembrando que estou partindo do "cenário" inicial: 3 commits (HEAD aponta para o terceiro commit 668185f), o arquivo no *staging area* tem 4 linhas e no *working dir* tem 5 linhas.

Esta opção faz o mesmo que `--soft` (move o HEAD para o commit indicado), mas não para por aí. Em seguida ele atualiza o *staging area* com o conteúdo que está neste commit:

```
$ git reset --mixed 8bc39c6
Unstaged changes after reset:
M   arq.txt
```

Agora o HEAD aponta para o commit 8bc39c6:

```
$ git log --oneline 
8bc39c6 (HEAD -> master) segundo commit
36da346 primeiro commit
```

E o *staging area* foi atualizado com o mesmo conteúdo do commit (tanto que o `reset` gerou a mensagem *"Unstaged changes after reset"*, indicando que algo foi alterado no *staging area*).

Podemos ver que `diff --cached` não mostra mais nenhuma diferença:

```
$ git diff --cached 
(não mostra nada)
```

Ou seja, o *staging area* está igual ao último commit (que no caso, é o segundo commit, no qual o arquivo só tem 2 linhas). Vamos conferir com `ls-files`:

```
$ git ls-files -s
100644 e2745035197cf4b209887f1fcc056f1afe7ff23d 0   arq.txt
```

O hash do arquivo mudou (não é mais "f9efd34b6e..."), o que indica que de fato o *staging area* foi alterado. Vamos ver o seu conteúdo:

```
$ git cat-file -p e2745035
primeiro
segundo
```

E de fato o *staging area* está com apenas duas linhas, idêntico ao segundo commit. Mas o arquivo no meu *working dir* continua com 5 linhas:

```
$ cat arq.txt 
primeiro
segundo
terceiro
quarto
quinto
```

### `--hard`

A opção `--hard` faz tudo que `--mixed` faz, mas também sobrescreve o conteúdo do meu *working dir*.

Lembrando que estou partindo do "cenário" inicial: 3 commits (HEAD aponta para o terceiro commit 668185f), o arquivo no *staging area* tem 4 linhas e no *working dir* tem 5 linhas.

```
$ git reset --hard 8bc39c6
HEAD is now at 8bc39c6 segundo commit
```

Primeiro vamos conferir se ele fez o mesmo que `--mixed`: o HEAD deve estar no segundo commit e o *staging area* deve estar igual a este commit (ou seja, o arquivo deve estar com duas linhas):

```
$ git log --oneline 
8bc39c6 (HEAD -> master) segundo commit
36da346 primeiro commit

$ git diff --cached
(não mostra nada)

$ git ls-files -s
100644 e2745035197cf4b209887f1fcc056f1afe7ff23d 0   arq.txt
$ git cat-file -p e2745035
primeiro
segundo
```

Como podemos ver, `--hard` fez o mesmo que `--mixed`. Mas ele fez algo a mais: meu *working dir* foi sobrescrito com o mesmo conteúdo do segundo commit:

```
$ cat arq.txt 
primeiro
segundo
```

---

### Resumindo

- `--soft`: move o HEAD para o outro commit
- `--mixed`: move o HEAD e sobrescreve o *staging area*
- `--hard`: move o HEAD, sobrescreve o *staging area* e o *working dir*

Este exemplo foi claramente <strike>copiado</strike> inspirado por [este artigo](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Reset-Demystified). Recomendo que leia, pois ele tem exemplos mais detalhados, principalmente para os casos em que você passa arquivos como parâmetros (pois aí o comportamento muda um pouco), entre outros casos de uso - mas como esses casos adicionais não são o foco da pergunta, resolvi parar por aqui, pois já ficou gigante.

Comment: PS: esqueci de mencionar que no meu ambiente o `git log` está como um [alias](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases) e na verdade o comando completo seria `git log --oneline --decorate`, que mostra `(HEAD -> master)` na saída (sem o `decorate`, isso não é mostrado).

Answer (score 6):

### Soft

Não toca no arquivo de índice ou na árvore de trabalho (mas redefine a cabeça, ou HEAD, assim como todos os modos). Isso deixa todos os seus arquivos alterados como "Mudanças a serem comitadas", como o status do git colocaria.

### Mixed

Redefine o índice, mas não a árvore de trabalho (ou seja, os arquivos alterados são preservados, mas não marcados para confirmação) e relata o que não foi atualizado. Esta é a ação padrão. Se -N for especificado, os caminhos removidos são marcados como intenção de adicionar.

### Hard

Redefine o índice e a árvore de trabalho. Quaisquer alterações nos arquivos rastreados na árvore de trabalho são descartadas.

---

Agora para melhorar entender os conceitos de repositório, working tree (árvore ou diretório de trabalho) e índice:

#### Repositório

O container que mantém todos os seus commits e arquivos dentro de uma determinada linha de tempo.

#### Árvore de trabalho

Comumente chamada de Working Tree, representa o diretório onde você realmente trabalha, modificando ou adicionando arquivos para serem futuramente comitados.

#### Índice ou staging area

Onde os commits são preparados, isto é, o índice compara os arquivos na árvore de trabalho com os arquivos no repositório e assim qualquer alteração na árvore de trabalho, é marcada pelo índice antes de ser confirmada.

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOpt FelipeMM! Agradeço sua resposta desde já, mas ainda tenho dúvidas. Acabei de ver sobre git, então não entendo quase nada! rs O que seria "arquivo índice" e "árvore de trabalho"?

Comment: soft: muda o index do HEAD ("cabeça" foi de matar...) para o último commit efetivamente realizado e as alterações feitas continuam na área de stage; mixed: mesma coisa do soft, exceto que as alterações não permanecem na área de stage (ou seja, você teria que dar git add novamente nos arquivos desejados); hard: move o HEAD para o último commit e remove FISICAMENTE suas alterações (portanto, use com cuidado).

Comment: rbz, funciona da seguinte forma:
Temos o repositório, a working tree (árvore de trabalho ou diretório de trabalho) e o índice.
O repositório é o container que mantém todos os seus commits e arquivos dentro de uma determinada linha de tempo. A árvore de trabalho é onde você realmente modifica ou adiciona arquivos para serem comitados. Já o índice ou staging area, é onde os commits são preparados, isto é, o índice compara os arquivos na árvore de trabalho com os arquivos no repositório e assim qualquer alteração na árvore de trabalho, é marcada pelo índice antes de ser confirmada.

Comment: Vocês me deram uma visão mais clara! O que gostaria FelipeMM, é que dessa forma que explicou, adicionasse isso na sua pergunta, duma forma explicativa para os total iniciantes em `git` (que é meu caso). Assim sua resposta ficaria bem completa, e isso é bom para os próximos que virem procurar sobre isso! Ajudaria muita gente! Dá uma caprichada dessa aí! rs ✌️

Comment: Perfeito rbz, irei fazê-lo

Answer (score 1):

**Reset Soft**
Desfaz Commite. Mantém Stage e modificações.

**Reset Mixed**
Desfaz Commit e Stage. Mantém modificações.

**Reset Hard**
Desfaz Commit, Stage e modificações.

Stage "são os arquivos selecionados para o Commit".