# Como retroceder o comando git add --all

Tags: git, commit, rollback

Acabei usando esse comando indevidamente, e adicionei muitos arquivos que não deveria, queria voltar o estado anterior, o comando `git reset HEAD <file>` retorna apenas um arquivo, e como são muitos fica inviável utilizar ele. Adicionei o nome do diretório ao arquivo `.gitignore`, porém quando rodava o comando `git status` era listado todos os arquivos na fase de serem commitados, eu não comitei, pois acredito se commitar e depois fazer o `push`, esses arquivos serão carregados(talvez esteja errado). Vi em um link do SO-pt que o comando `git reset HEAD *` retornaria todas as mudanças ao estado `untracked`, os arquivos que voltaram a esse estado foi exatamente o arquivo `.gitignore` e não os arquivos que tinha adicionado anteriormente. Como faço para voltar?

Comment: Tente apenas `git reset`.

Comment: Use  `git reset .`  com espaço e ponto depois do reset

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/325951/112052

Answer (score 1):

Temos um exemplo disso no [manual do git online](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset#_examples)

```
$ edit                                     
$ git add frotz.c filfre.c                 (1)
$ mailx                                    (2)
$ git reset                                (3)
$ git pull git://info.example.com/ nitfol  (4)
```

O exemplo é o seguinte: tu estás trabalhando em algo e decides adicionar arquivos que tens certeza que estão bons. (1)

Aí, alguém faz uma alteração importante, que, apesar de não fazer parte diretamente do teu trabalho, é nos mesmos arquivos. (2)

Todavia, como tu já adicionaste algo, teu index já é diferente, e fazer um pull causaria conflito. Para solucionar, a melhor forma é fazer um `reset` antes de fazer um `pull` das alterações que estão na base. O `add` é desfeito, mas as alterações são mantidas.(3)

Assim quando fizeres um pull, tu podes fazer um merge (se não for automático). Aí tu continuas sincronizado com a base, sem perder tuas alterações.(4)

(A pseudo-tradução do link não está 100% fiel, pois tentei explicar mais com minhas palavras mesmo)

Comment: Depois no caso é necessário apenas adicionar ao `stage` e `commitar` ambos?

Comment: Depois, `git add <arquivos alterados>`, `git commit` e, finalmente `git push` para que as alterações não fiquem local

Answer (score 0):

Digitei o comando `git log` e copiei a *hash* de um *commit* anterior, logo depois utilizei o comando `git reset --hard hash`.

**P.S.:** *hash* referente ao *commit*

Comment: Isso [descarta alterações](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset). Melhor usar sem o --hard