# Como desfazer merge mantendo as alterações feitas após

Tags: git, merge

O branch `feature` teve um merge de `aleatorio`.

Como excluir esse merge mantendo as alterações efetuadas em `feature`, antes e depois do merge efetuado?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Creio que você terá um trampo manual. Pois ao meu ver, teria que voltar o merge com git reset ou git revert e copiar os arquivos/alterações novas para o repositório que você desfez o merge.

Comment: Esse link simula alguns casos, talvez te ajude: http://dojo.objectos.com.br/caixa/git-04-resolver_merge_incorreto.html

Answer (score 3):

Para casos assim, eu prefiro criar um branch temporário, fazer as alterações nele e só no final, eu mudo o branch que quero (no caso, *feature*) para apontar para este branch temporário.

Então primeiro temos que criar o branch temporário (que chamarei pelo criativo nome de "temp"), fazendo com que ele aponte para o commit C9 (que é o último commit antes do merge):

```bsh
git checkout -b temp C9
```

> A partir do [Git 2.23.0 (lançado em 2019)](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.23.0.txt), também é possível usar o comando
> `switch` (explicado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/533866/112052)):
>
> ```bsh
> git switch -c temp C9
> ```

Obviamente, você deve trocar "C9" pelo hash do respectivo commit.

Com o comando acima, o branch *temp* é criado e eu já estarei nele (o conteúdo do meu diretório será o mesmo do commit C9).

Em seguida, você pode usar [`git cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) para aplicar um grupo de commits:

```bsh
git cherry-pick C11^..C12
```

Assim, serão aplicados todos os commits de C11 a C12 (importante notar o `^` logo depois do C11, para que este seja incluído). Se tivesse mais commits (por exemplo, de C11 a C20, bastaria fazer `C11^..C20`).

*Nesse caso, como são apenas dois commits, também seria possível fazer `git cherry-pick C11 C12` <- esta opção também é útil quando os commits não estão em sequência (poderia ser um commit de cada branch sem nenhuma relação entre eles, por exemplo, e aí a sintaxe `C11^..C12` não funcionaria).*

No caso, o comando `cherry-pick` verifica, para cada commit da lista, quais as alterações feitas por aquele commit e aplica ao branch atual. Ou seja, primeiro ele pega o C11 e aplica (criando **outro** commit, mas mantendo as mesmas alterações e o mesmo comentário). Depois faz o mesmo com C12.

Agora o branch *temp* possui as mesmas alterações dos commits C11 e C12 (e não tem o merge com o branch "aleatorio"), mas é importante salientar que **são commits diferentes**, já que a data dos mesmos não é a mesma dos commits originais (e se foi outra pessoa que fez, os autores também serão diferentes - somente as alterações e o comentário do commit é que são iguais).

---

Agora é só voltar para o branch *feature* e fazer ele apontar para o branch *temp*:

```bsh
git checkout feature # ou "git switch feature", para Git >= 2.23.0
git reset --hard temp
```

E por fim, apagamos o branch *temp*, pois não precisamos mais dele:

```bsh
git branch -d temp
```

Com isso, o branch *feature* agora possui as alterações do commit C11 e C12. Mas novamente, não são exatamente os mesmos commits, pois as datas não são as mesmas - e o autor também pode não ser. Somente as alterações e os comentários dos commits são os mesmos. Por isso, os commits C11 e C12 originais serão perdidos (caso não seja possível chegar a eles por nenhum outro branch).

---

Sobre o `reset --hard`, você pode ver mais detalhes [no manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) e [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/325951/112052).