# Como reverter um git reset hard

Tags: git, github

Tenho uma pasta na minha máquina, que quando atualizo dou commit no GitHub.

Acontece que fiz algumas boas alterações, e fui fazer o commit. Fiz:

```
git add -A
git commit -m "..."
git push -u origin master
```

Só que desisti de mandar para o git, então apertei <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, mas a partir daí o git mostrava a mensagem dizendo que eu tinha 1 commit pendente (ou seja, minhas alterações feitas no dia ainda **não** estavam no GitHub, apenas no PC).

A fim de eliminar essa mensagem, fiz:

```
git reset hard
```

E finalmente quando eu digitava `git status`, não vinha mais a mensagem dizendo que eu tinha um commit pendente.

Mas agora as minhas alterações feitas no PC (na pasta que dou commit para o git) tinham sido desfeitas, arquivos deletados. Alguém sabe como fazer esses arquivos e alterações voltarem para esta pasta no meu PC?

Tentei `git revert` mas ele apenas volta ao que já estava no GitHub e, como eu disse no começo, essas alterações não estavam no GitHub porque não esperei concluir o comando `git push`, ou seja, essas alterações estavam apenas no PC.

Comment: Se vc já tinha dado um push na master, da um qit pull de volta no local...

Comment: entao, mas, dei um ctrl+c antes do push concluir, e depois revert, e o que ficou no git foram outras alterações passadas

Comment: então da o Ctrl+V da pasta uai

Comment: entendeste errado. ctrl+c no terminal quando estava executando o comando push -u origin master, ou seja, eu interrompi o push. Só isso. Não tem a ver com copiar e colar amigo kkk. No texto aí em cima eu explico o passo a passo que eu fiz

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6OokP-NE49k isso aqui deve te ajudar

Comment: Obrigado amigo, vai me ajudar a usar melhor o git. Mas pelo visto, as alterações nao voltam, já que eu nao tinha mandado pro github ainda. Mas obrigado mesmo assim, vai me ajudar daqui para frente.

Comment: O `git reset --hard` apaga tudo o que tinha salvo anteriormente, por isso deve ser usado com cautela. Mas você não passou o id do commit antes de fazer o `--hard`?

Comment: `git reset --hard` de fato apaga as alterações locais ([veja aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/325951/112052) mais detalhes sobre como ele funciona), mas *talvez* vc ainda consiga recuperar o commit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21778

Comment: Acredito que não dê pra reverter, acho que você queria colocar os arquivos na área de [stash](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)

Comment: @AndréOliveira, não é relacionado ao Git a minha solução, mas se estava usando alguma IDE, talvez ela tenha ainda no seu histórico os arquivos que foram removidos. No Intellij é assim: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2008/01/using-local-history-to-restore-deleted-files/

Comment: ja usou o git reflog ? Ele vai informar os commits anteriores com seus indices