# Revertendo o commit

Tags: git, terminal, commit

Fala galera, estou com um problema no meu repositório.

Quero reverter o repositório para um commit  anterior, no caso seria o commit que está em vermelho.

```
commit 2c593e6aa3d1a9f4c8f044618a04b2f2b5b57388 (origin/master, origin/HEAD)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se quiser manter as modificações do último commit (elas ficaram na área de *stage*)

```bsh
git reset --soft HEAD^
```

Se preferir descartá-las

```bsh
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

Também é possível informar o hash do commit para o qual você deseja apontar

```bsh
git reset --<soft|hard> 2c593e
```

Veja mais detalhes na documentação do [`git reset`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset)

Comment: No caso quero descartar mesmo, mas o --hard ele remove somente o primeiro, é isso? E ai no caso ficaria o do dia 27 as 14:11 ?

Comment: @RomuloSousa O que diz que é o primeiro é o `HEAD^` que quer dizer "vá para o commit que está logo atrás do HEAD"

Comment: Entendi, para mim resolveria usar o commit ` 2c593e`, o soft daria certo. Só uma pergunta com isso ele excluiria o commit que estária errado?

Comment: Os dois removem o commit. A diferença é que o *hard* mata as modificações, você perde elas. O **soft** mantém as modificações na área de stage.

Comment: Note que isso não vai alterar o repositório remoto, apenas o local.

Comment: @RomuloSousa Sobre as opções do `git reset`, veja aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/325951/112052